# php - parsing xml and inserting data into mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, xml, codeigniter

I am parsing data in my php script from external xml file using "simplexml_load_file($xmlFile)" function. The xml source files pushed to the server using ftp by external data-supplieris. Parsed data inserted into MySQL database. There are two correspondent php scripts which are responsible for doing this task. These php scripts load two different xml files.

My problem is, most of the time data are passed to the database but not always. Sometimes the entries are missing for the "lastgoaltime" field. For example, data are imported for a football match. There are entries before the half time, but data missing started to occur after the half time. And that happens not for all matches, only for two specific leagues with the league ID "66" and "86".

```
($LigaId=="66") {$league="International";}
($LigaId=="86") {$league="Testspiele";}
```

the main.php file gathers data from main.xml file for the whole data sets and _delta.php gathers data from _delta.xml file only if there is any recent update. The cron job is done by a cron.sh file stated in the unix server for every 1 minute interval.

### **cron.sh file-**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/lynx -dump https://www.example.com/dev/main.php 2>&1
sleep 2
c=1
while [ $c -le 56 ]
do
/usr/bin/lynx -dump https://www.example.com/dev/_delta.php 2>&1
(( c++ ))
sleep 1
done
```

I have researched the source xml files, and they contains data properly. I think there is some mismatch in my php script.

Points to be noted that I am using CodeIgniter framework for the whole project as well.

could you please provide some clue that might help me to resolve my issue? Here is the codes from my script and from the xml-

### **main.php**

```
<?php 

  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $xmlFile='main.xml';

  $xmltime=0;
  $sessionTime=-1;
  $tournament="";
  $country="";
  $m_timestamp=0;
  $p_timestamp=0;
  $teamnamehome="";
  $teamnameaway="";
  $scorehome="-";
  $scoreaway="-";
  $status="";
  $matchId=0;
  $lastgoalteam=0;
  $lastgoaltime=0;
  $minscored=0;
  $lastgoalscoredby="";

    echo time()."- start importing livescores.\n";
    if (file_exists($xmlFile)) { 
     $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile); 
    echo "<br>xml Datei vorhanden\n";
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');

    if (!$link) {
    die('Verbindung schlug fehl: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
    echo 'Verbindung steht';
    }

    mysql_select_db('base');    
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    if($xml) { 

                $generatedTime=$xml['generatedAt'];
                $xmlcounter=$xml['counter'];
                //echo "<br>test".$generatedTime;
                $XMLDATE=$generatedTime;
                $x_jahr=substr($XMLDATE,0,4);
                $x_monat=substr($XMLDATE,5,2);
                $x_tag=substr($XMLDATE,8,2);
                $x_stunde=substr($XMLDATE,11,2);
                $x_minute=substr($XMLDATE,14,2);
                $xmltime= mktime($x_stunde,$x_minute,0,$x_monat,$x_tag,$x_jahr);
        echo "<br>XMLZEIT: ".$xmltime;   // hier hast du also deine XML Zeit, die du weiter unten in die DB einbauen kannst!!!

        //          foreach($xml->Tournament as $sport) {
        foreach ($xml->children() as $sport) {
        //$getHeaderAttributes=$sport->attributes();
        //if($getHeaderAttributes[generatedAt]!=""){
        //echo $getHeaderAttributes;
        //}

        if ($sport->Name=="Soccer" ){echo "<br>Sportart:Soccer";
            foreach ($sport->children() as $category) {
                    //echo "category: ";
                if($category->Name=="Germany" || $category->Name=="Spain" || $category->Name=="International Clubs" || $category->Name=="England" || $category->Name=="Turkey" || $category->Name=="Italy" || $category->Name=="International" || $category->Name=="Argentina" || $category->Name=="Australia" || $category->Name=="Austria" || $category->Name=="Belgium" || $category->Name=="Denmark" || $category->Name=="France" || $category->Name=="Germany Amateur" || $category->Name=="Greece" || $category->Name=="Holland" || $category->Name=="Mexico" || $category->Name=="Portugal" || $category->Name=="Russia" || $category->Name=="Scotland" || $category->Name=="Switzerland" || $category->Name=="Ukraine" || $category->Name=="USA" ){

                    $country=$category->Name;
                    echo "<br>Organisation: ".$country;

                    foreach ($category->children() as $tournament) {
                    $LigaId=$tournament->attributes();

                    if($LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="42" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="66" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10771" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10772" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="41" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="23" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10909" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="36" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="16" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="8343" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="43" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="150" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="62" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="33" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="86"|| $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="16527"|| $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10910"|| $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="680"|| $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="6456"|| $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="3959"|| $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1339"|| $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="3948"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1462"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1463"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1464"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1465"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1466"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1467"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1468"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1469"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10908"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10911"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10912"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10913"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10914"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10915"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10916"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10917"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10918"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10919"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10920"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="10921"  || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="4508" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="4509" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="4510" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="4511" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="4512" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="4513" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="4514" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="5346" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="5347" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="68" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="29" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="38" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="12" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="4" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="21299" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="44" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="21301" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="21300" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="8364" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="127" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="39" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="28" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="52" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="53" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="54" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="1060" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="384" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="18" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="17" || $LigaId['BetradarTournamentId']=="144" ){
      echo "<br>TurnierId: ".$LigaId['BetradarTournamentId'];
                            //echo $tournament->Name;
                            //echo time();
                        foreach ($tournament->children() as $match){
                            $matchId=$match->attributes();
                            $uniqueTeamIdHome=$match->Team1->attributes();
                            $uniqueTeamIdAway=$match->Team2->attributes();
                            if($match->MatchDate[0]!="" && $match->Team1->Name[0]!="" && $match->Team2->Name[0]!=""){
                                //normalisiere Datum aus Form: 2014-03-28T20:30:00 CET
                                $DateFromXml=$match->MatchDate[0];
                                $jahr=substr($DateFromXml,0,4);
                                $monat=substr($DateFromXml,5,2);
                                $tag=substr($DateFromXml,8,2);
                                $stunde=substr($DateFromXml,11,2);
                                $minute=substr($DateFromXml,14,2);
                                $m_timestamp= mktime($stunde,$minute,0,$monat,$tag,$jahr);

                                //echo $match->MatchDate[0];
                                $teamnamehome=$match->Team1->Name[0];                                                   
                                $teamnamehome=substr($teamnamehome,0,50);
                                //to replace quote mark from xml attribut as string value
                                    $findstr  = "'";
                                    $pos = strpos($teamnamehome, $findstr);

                                    if ($pos !== false) {
                                        $teamnamehome = str_replace($findstr, "&#39", $teamnamehome);;
                                    }
                                    //end of replace

                                $teamnameaway=$match->Team2->Name[0];
                                $teamnameaway=substr($teamnameaway,0,50);
                                //to replace quote mark from xml attribut as string value
                                    $findstr  = "'";
                                    $pos = strpos($teamnameaway, $findstr);

                                    if ($pos !== false) {
                                        $teamnameaway = str_replace($findstr, "&#39", $teamnameaway);;
                                    }
                                    //end of replace

                                echo "<br>".$teamnamehome."< - >".$teamnameaway."<br>";
                                //echo $match->Team1->Name[0]."</td><td class=\"ls_team2\">".$match->Team2->Name[0]."</td><td class=\"ls_status_result\">";                         
                                    if ($match->Status->Name=="Not started"){
                                    $status=$match->Status->Name;
                                    //echo " - : - </td></tr>";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $status=$match->Status->Name;
                                        echo $status;
                                            //wenn status erste oder zweite HZ, dann ermittle acttime-periodstarttime
                                            if($status=="1st half" || $status=="2nd half" || $status=="1st extra" || $status=="2nd extra"){
                                                //normiere PeriodStartZeit und wandel in timestamp
                                                $timePlayedXml=$match->CurrentPeriodStart;
                                                $p_jahr=substr($timePlayedXml,0,4);
                                                $p_monat=substr($timePlayedXml,5,2);
                                                $p_tag=substr($timePlayedXml,8,2);
                                                $p_stunde=substr($timePlayedXml,11,2);
                                                $p_minute=substr($timePlayedXml,14,2);
                                                $p_timestamp= mktime($p_stunde,$p_minute,0,$p_monat,$p_tag,$p_jahr);
                                                $sessionTime=round((time()-$p_timestamp)/60);
                                                //echo "<tr><th colspan=\"3\">timeplayed".$p_timestamp."-".$sessionTime."</th></tr>";
                                                echo $sessionTime;
                                                $lastgoalteam=$match->LastGoal->Team;

                                                $lastgoaltime_raw=$match->LastGoal->Time;

                                                $lg_jahr=substr($lastgoaltime_raw,0,4);
                                                $lg_monat=substr($lastgoaltime_raw,5,2);
                                                $lg_tag=substr($lastgoaltime_raw,8,2);
                                                $lg_stunde=substr($lastgoaltime_raw,11,2);
                                                $lg_minute=substr($lastgoaltime_raw,14,2);
                                                $lastgoaltime= mktime($lg_stunde,$lg_minute,0,$lg_monat,$lg_tag,$lg_jahr);

                                            //echo "hier";

                                            }
                                        foreach($match->children() as $scores){
                                            if($scores->Score->Team1!="" && $scores->Score->Team2!=""){
                                    //          echo $scores->Score->Team1." : ".$scores->Score->Team2."</td></tr>";
                                                $scorehome=$scores->Score->Team1;
                                                $scoreaway=$scores->Score->Team2;
                                                //echo "here";
                                                if($scores->Score->Team1!="0" || $scores->Score->Team2!="0"){

                                                    $count = $match->Goals->Goal->count();
                                                    //echo "here2";
                                                    $minscored=$match->Goals->Goal[($count-1)]->Time;
                                                    $lastgoalscoredby=$match->Goals->Goal[($count-1)]->Player;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                            if($sessionTime>0){
                                                    if ($status=="1st half"){
                                                        echo "1. Halbzeit / ".$sessionTime." min";
                                                    }
                                                    else if ($status=="2nd half"){
                                                        $sessionTime=$sessionTime+45;
                                                        echo "2. Halbzeit / ".$sessionTime." min";
                                                    }
                                                    else if ($status=="1st extra"){
                                                        $sessionTime=$sessionTime+90;
                                            //          echo "2. Halbzeit / ".$sessionTime." min";
                                                    }
                                                    else if ($status=="2nd extra"){
                                                        $sessionTime=$sessionTime+105;
                                            //          echo "2. Halbzeit / ".$sessionTime." min";
                                                    }
                                                    else if ($status=="Halftime"){
                                                        echo "Halbzeit";
                                                    }

                                                    else {
                                                     $sessionTime=$sessionTime+1;
                                                    }

                                                }
                                    }
                            }

                            $matchId2db=$matchId['Id'];
                            $league=0;
                            $uniqueTeamIdHome2db=$uniqueTeamIdHome['UniqueTeamId']."_";
                            $uniqueTeamIdAway2db=$uniqueTeamIdAway['UniqueTeamId']."_";
                            if($LigaId=="41"){$league="2. Bundesliga";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="42"){$league="Bundesliga";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="8343") {$league="3. Liga";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="43") {$league="DFB Pokal";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="66") {$league="International";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1462"){$league="Champions League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1463"){$league="Champions League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1464"){$league="Champions League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1465"){$league="Champions League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1466"){$league="Champions League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1467"){$league="Champions League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1468"){$league="Champions League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1469"){$league="Champions League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10908") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10911") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10912") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10913") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10914") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10915") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10916") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10917") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10918") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10919") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10920") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10921") {$league="Europa League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10910") {$league="UEFA Europa League, Qualification";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="36") {$league="Primera Division";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="150") {$league="Copa del Rey";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1") {$league="Premier League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="16") {$league="FA Cup";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="62") {$league="Süper Lig";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="86" || $LigaId=="689") {$league="Testspiele";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="16527") {$league="Telekom Cup";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="3956") {$league="WM Gruppe C";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="680") {$league="UEFA Supercup";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="6456") {$league="DFB Supercup";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1339") {$league="Champions League Qualification";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="3960") {$league="WM Gruppe G";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="3961") {$league="WM Gruppe H";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="3948") {$league="WM Achtelfinale";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="4508") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group A";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="4509") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group B";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="4510") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group C";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="4511") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group D";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="4512") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group E";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="4513") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group F";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="4514") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group G";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="5346") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group H";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="5347") {$league="European Championship, Qualification Group I";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="33") {$league="Serie A";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="10771" || $LigaId=="10772") {$league="Bundesliga Relegation";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="68") {$league="Primera Division";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="29") {$league="Bundesliga";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="38") {$league="Pro League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="12") {$league="Superligaen";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="4") {$league="Ligue 1";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="21299") {$league="Regionalliga Bavaria";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="44") {$league="Regionalliga North";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="21301") {$league="Regionalliga Northeast";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="21300") {$league="Regionalliga Southwest";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="8364") {$league="Regionalliga West";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="127") {$league="Super League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="39") {$league="Eredivisie";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="28") {$league="Primera Division";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="52") {$league="Primeira Liga";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="53") {$league="Premier League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="54") {$league="Premiership";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="1060") {$league="Super League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="384") {$league="Premier League";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="18") {$league="Major League Soccer";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="17") {$league="League Cup";}
                            else if ($LigaId=="144") {$league="A-League";}
                            if ($league=="0") {
                             $league=$tournamentname;   
                            }

                            $tournamentname="No name found";

                            if($teamnamehome=="" || $teamnameaway=="" || $matchId2db<10){}
                            else{
                                $jetzt=time();
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO `matches_soccer` (matchid,country,league,matchdate,matchstatus,hometeam,awayteam,lastperioddate,scorehome,scoreaway,lastgoaltime, uniqueTeamHome, uniqueTeamAway, lastgoalteam, scoremin, scoredby, createtime,lastchangeby,xmltime) VALUES ('$matchId2db','$country', '$league', '$m_timestamp','$status','$teamnamehome','$teamnameaway','$p_timestamp','$scorehome','$scoreaway','$lastgoaltime','$uniqueTeamIdHome2db','$uniqueTeamIdAway2db','$lastgoalteam', '$minscored','$lastgoalscoredby','$jetzt','main','$xmltime') ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                                UPDATE `matchid` = VALUES(matchid), `country` = VALUES(country), `league` = VALUES(league), `matchdate` = VALUES(matchdate), `matchstatus` = VALUES(matchstatus), `hometeam` = VALUES(hometeam), `awayteam` = VALUES(awayteam), `lastperioddate` = VALUES(lastperioddate), `scorehome` = VALUES(scorehome),`scoreaway` = VALUES(scoreaway),`lastgoaltime` = VALUES(lastgoaltime),`uniqueTeamHome` = VALUES(uniqueTeamHome),`uniqueTeamAway` = VALUES(uniqueTeamAway),`lastgoalteam` = VALUES(lastgoalteam),`scoremin` = VALUES(scoremin),`scoredby` = VALUES(scoredby),`createtime` = VALUES(createtime),`lastchangeby` = VALUES(lastchangeby),`xmltime` = VALUES(xmltime)");
                                echo mysql_errno(),
                                "<br>",
                                mysql_error();

       $checkrows = mysql_query("SELECT `matchid` FROM `ls_matches_soccer` where `matchid` = '$matchId2db' AND '$xmltime' > `xmltime` Limit 1");
                                echo mysql_errno(),
                                "<br>",
                                mysql_error();
                                $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($checkrows);
                                $row = mysql_fetch_array($checkrows);

                                if ($num_rows<1){
                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `matches_soccer` (matchid,country,league,matchdate,matchstatus,hometeam,awayteam,lastperioddate,scorehome,scoreaway,lastgoaltime, uniqueTeamHome, uniqueTeamAway, lastgoalteam, scoremin, scoredby, createtime,lastchangeby,xmltime) VALUES ('$matchId2db','$country', '$league', '$m_timestamp','$status','$teamnamehome','$teamnameaway','$p_timestamp','$scorehome','$scoreaway','$lastgoaltime','$uniqueTeamIdHome2db','$uniqueTeamIdAway2db','$lastgoalteam', '$minscored','$lastgoalscoredby','$jetzt','main','$xmltime') ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                                UPDATE `matchid` = VALUES(matchid), `country` = VALUES(country), `league` = VALUES(league), `matchdate` = VALUES(matchdate), `matchstatus` = VALUES(matchstatus), `hometeam` = VALUES(hometeam), `awayteam` = VALUES(awayteam), `lastperioddate` = VALUES(lastperioddate), `scorehome` = VALUES(scorehome),`scoreaway` = VALUES(scoreaway),`lastgoaltime` = VALUES(lastgoaltime),`uniqueTeamHome` = VALUES(uniqueTeamHome),`uniqueTeamAway` = VALUES(uniqueTeamAway),`lastgoalteam` = VALUES(lastgoalteam),`scoremin` = VALUES(scoremin),`scoredby` = VALUES(scoredby),`createtime` = VALUES(createtime),`lastchangeby` = VALUES(lastchangeby),`xmltime` = VALUES(xmltime)");
                                echo mysql_errno(),
                                "<br>",
                                mysql_error();
                                $num_rows=0;
                                echo "test".$status;
                                    $eintragen = "XMLTime: ".$xmltime."  ".$teamnamehome."-".$teamnameaway."  ".$scorehome.":".$scoreaway."  -- ".$status;
                                    $logname="20141120_main_xml2db.log";
                                    $datei=fopen($logname,"a");
                                    fputs($datei,"$eintragen\n\n");
                                    fclose($datei);
                                }
              else {

                                    $logname="20141120_main_xml2db.log";
                                    $datei=fopen($logname,"a");
                                    $eintragen=date('d.M.Y-H:i:s',$jetzt)."-".$xmlcounter."-Match bereits von delta aktualisiert<br>!";
                                    fputs($datei,"$eintragen\n\n");
                                    fclose($datei);
                                }
                                echo mysql_errno(),"<br>",mysql_error();
                                $scorehome="-";
                                $scoreaway="-";
                                $lastgoaltime=0;
                                $lastgoalteam=0;
                                $minscored=0;
                                $lastgoalscoredby="";
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        }


      }
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

### **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BetradarLivescoreData generatedAt="2014-12-01T10:28:21 CET" generatedFor="3447" type="full">
<Sport BetradarSportId="1">
<Name>Soccer</Name>
<Category BetradarCategoryId="48">
<Name>Argentina</Name>
<Tournament BetradarTournamentId="68" UniqueTournamentId="155">
<Name language="en">Primera Division</Name>
<Name>Primera Division</Name>
<Match BetradarMatchId="8490493" Id="5656356">
<MatchDate>2014-12-01T22:10:00 CET</MatchDate>
<Team1 BetradarTeamId="833344" UniqueTeamId="6074">
<Name language="en">Godoy Cruz A.t.</Name>
</Team1>
<Team2 BetradarTeamId="118091" UniqueTeamId="3222">
<Name language="en">Olimpo Bahia Blanca</Name>
</Team2>
<Status Code="0">
<Name language="en">Not started</Name>
</Status>
<Winner>0</Winner>
<Referee id="249775" name="Delfino, German">
<Country id="10" name="Argentina">
<Name language="en">Argentina</Name>
</Country>
</Referee>
<Venue>
<Country id="10" name="Argentina">
<Name language="en">Argentina</Name>
</Country>
<City id="1176" name="Mendoza">
<Name language="en">Mendoza</Name>
</City>
<Stadium id="2249" name="Estadio Feliciano Gambarte">
<Name language="en">Estadio Feliciano Gambarte</Name>
</Stadium>
</Venue>
</Match>
<Match BetradarMatchId="8490498" Id="5656366">
<MatchDate>2014-12-02T00:30:00 CET</MatchDate>
<Team1 BetradarTeamId="118090" UniqueTeamId="3221">
<Name language="en">Arsenal De Sarandi</Name>
</Team1>
<Team2 BetradarTeamId="8904" UniqueTeamId="3203">
<Name language="en">CA Belgrano</Name>
</Team2>
<Status Code="0">
<Name language="en">Not started</Name>
</Status>
<Winner>0</Winner>
<Referee id="249761" name="Ceballos, Diego">
<Country id="10" name="Argentina">
<Name language="en">Argentina</Name>
</Country>
</Referee>
<Venue>
<Country id="10" name="Argentina">
<Name language="en">Argentina</Name>
</Country>
<City id="427" name="Sarandi">
<Name language="en">Sarandi</Name>
</City>
<Stadium id="586" name="Estadio Julio Humberto Grondona">
<Name language="en">Estadio Julio Humberto Grondona</Name>
</Stadium>
</Venue>
</Match>
</Tournament>
</Category>
<Category BetradarCategoryId="66">
<Name>Israel</Name>
<Tournament BetradarTournamentId="877" UniqueTournamentId="266">
<Name language="en">Premier League</Name>
<Name>Premier League</Name>
<Match BetradarMatchId="8446321" Id="5820536">
<MatchDate>2014-12-01T19:00:00 CET</MatchDate>
<Team1 BetradarTeamId="141994" UniqueTeamId="5204">
<Name language="en">Beitar Jerusalem</Name>
</Team1>
<Team2 BetradarTeamId="144177" UniqueTeamId="5333">
<Name language="en">Maccabi Petach Tikva</Name>
</Team2>
<Status Code="0">
<Name language="en">Not started</Name>
</Status>
<Winner>0</Winner>
<Venue>
<Country id="104" name="Israel">
<Name language="en">Israel</Name>
</Country>
<City id="2752" name="Jerusalem">
<Name language="en">Jerusalem</Name>
</City>
<Stadium id="4054" name="Teddy Stadium">
<Name language="en">Teddy Stadium</Name>
</Stadium>
</Venue>
</Match>
</Tournament>
</Category>
</Sport>
</BetradarLivescoreData>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're using CodeIgniter you've really got no excuse for using the deprecated `mysql_query` interface instead of the [framework's database layer](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/index.html). This looks full of severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: The XML file you provide doesn't have a LastGoal element in it.

Comment: Though I am using CodeIgniter, but these scripts work separately. So, mysql_query is not that issue.

Comment: This is a common form of my source xml file. This, file does not contains lastgoaltime tag, whenever there will be a match and that match will have last goal then it will contain that data.